# Virtual host does not seems to work

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

It seems that the most basic virtual host does not work under apache 2.2 :

```
# httpd.conf
Listen 80
....
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

the httpd-vhosts :

```
# httpd-vhosts.conf
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.dev
    ServerAlias lol.project.dev
    ServerAlias shootmania.project.dev

    DirectoryIndex "app.php"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/tb/workspace/project/web"
    <Directory "/Users/tb/workspace/project/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's what output apachectl :

```
apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
         default server project.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:21)
         port 80 namevhost project.dev (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:21)
         port 80 namevhost pow (/private/etc/apache2/other/zzz_pow.conf:1)
Syntax OK
```

In my [pow](http://pow.cx/) configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName pow 
  ServerAlias *.dev 
  ServerAlias *.xip.io 
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:20559/ 
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:20559/ 
  ProxyPreserveHost On 
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing to `localhost` defaults on the project website, but accessing to `http://project.dev` **gives a 404 Not found**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: The error log is empty for project.dev but for the global one : `[Sun Mar 09 19:40:24 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Comment: @Tristan Is that during the current service start?  That shouldn't be possible given the `apachectl -S` output.

Comment: Yes @ShaneMadden its during service start

Comment: @Tristan What's the `pow` vhost doing?  And from your access logs, are the requests to localhost being served by the `project.dev` virtual host?

Comment: pow vhost: ```<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName pow
  ServerAlias *.dev
  ServerAlias *.xip.io

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:20559/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:20559/
  ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
``` and no, the localhost isn't served by the project.dev virtual host :'(

Comment: pow vhost: ServerAlias *.dev
isn't that a problem?

Comment: I uninstalled pow, and removed rules in firewall that pow installs, and it works like a charm. Pow was the responsible for that :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstalled pow, and removed rules in firewall that pow installs, and it works like a charm. Pow was the responsible for that :/

Answer (score 0):

Your pow vhost configuration defines "ServerAlias *.dev" which overlaps your other VirtualHosts.

Comment: It always double-lists the one that's being used as default - that should be normal :)

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, it does point to the same configuration.